# Selecting an arbitrary cell in a table by row and column number

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a large table, and I need to be able to select a specific cell using it's cell/row coordinates.

What's the most elegant way of doing this using jQuery?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is one case where I think using native JavaScript actually makes the code easier to understand:

```
var table = $("#table")[0];
var cell = table.rows[1].cells[1]; // This is a DOM "TD" element
var $cell = $(cell); // Now it's a jQuery object.
```

Note that just selecting the `table` element will make `rows` include those rows in your `thead` (and `tfoot`). What you probably want is:

```
var table = $("#table tbody")[0];
/* remaining code from above */
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/CgqQt/

Comment: It seems like you can do `.rows().cells()` on jQuery objects. It's saying that the result doesn't have a `.css` method though. http://jsfiddle.net/CGrP9/1/

Comment: @Acorn: `$("table")[0]` is not a jQuery object anymore, it's a DOM element (you've accessed the first element in the list of matched elements), and subsequent calls to DOM properties (like `rows`) are also DOM elements (which is why they don't have a `css` method). Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/STLSN/

Comment: Thanks for the working example! Thinking about the bigger picture, is this a good way to be selecting the cells? Would it be more efficient to add a row/column id or class to each cell? Or is the above fairly efficient? I suppose I could just wrap it up in a nice function.

Comment: @Acorn: I'm not actually sure about how efficient it is. I imagine if you have tons of DOM elements on the page, you're going to have efficiency problems no matter what. Additionally, you have to take ease of development into account. Is it easier to write and maintain code that accesses table cells by index, or assign and manage unique `id`s for each cell? Premature optimization is often a bad idea. That said, check out http://jsperf.com for a good place to compare JavaScript speed :)

Answer (score 6):

After reviewing the fiddle you posted in one of your comments, this could also work.

http://jsfiddle.net/CGrP9/6/

```
$('tbody tr').eq(2).find('td').eq(2).css('background-color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this selects the cell at coordinate `(9, 9)`. Let me test:

```
$('table tr:eq(10) > td:eq(10)')
```

Comment: Not sure if having a `tbody` it would not work. Should it be `$('table tr:eq(10) > td:eq(10)')`

Comment: I tried using .eq(#) .. but it doesn't seem to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/CGrP9/

Answer (score 0):

$($("table#wall_layout tr")[row]).find("td")[col]