# Selecting a table cell by row and column while compensating for rowspan and colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to be able to select a table cell by row and column indices, while compensating for `rowspan` and `colspan`. For example, in the following table,

[image: example table]

I would expect coloring (1,2) red, (2,3) green, and (3,3) blue, to yield:

[image: expected table]

I tried the answer to the question, ["Selecting an arbitrary cell in a table by row and column number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930892/selecting-an-arbitrary-cell-in-a-table-by-row-and-column-number), but this yielded:

[image: actual table]

**[Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acheong87/27HuN/](http://jsfiddle.net/acheong87/27HuN/)**

I understand what is happening, and I even found another question, ["Table cellIndex and rowIndex with colspan/rowspan"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407348/table-cellindex-and-rowindex-with-colspan-rowspan), where an answer was supplied as a plugin, but it just seems unbelievable that there isn't a simpler way! After all, the coloring of the actual result seems understandable, yet unintuitive, while the coloring of the *expected* result seems far more intuitive and easily graspable.

**Can anyone think of a clever and simpler way to implement this?**

---

**Update**

[Here's a new jsFiddle with my (poor) attempt,](http://jsfiddle.net/acheong87/B4kV5/) in case it might inspire a new idea in someone else. Basically, *if* we assumed the row and col headers weren't spanned (which, of course, isn't a valid assumption), then we could use offsets to "target" the correct cell:

```
function getCell(table, r, c)
{
    var rowHead = $(table.rows[r].cells[0]);
    var colHead = $(table.rows[0].cells[c]);
    var y = rowHead.offset().top + rowHead.outerHeight(true)/2;
    var x = colHead.offset().left + colHead.outerWidth(true)/2;
    return $(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));
}
```

While the demo appears to work, there are a number of problems:

1. Can't assume row and col headers aren't spanned.
2. Doesn't work if midpoint of row or col is off the viewport; `elementFromPoint` seems to depend on the viewport.
3. Doesn't work reliably when scrolling, margins, etc. come into play; flimsy in general; would rather not rely on coordinate-math.

Comment: And what of more complex models? You are asking for something generic to solve every situation not just this one you say, so here is a worst case scenario example of the table: http://jsfiddle.net/27HuN/25/ .

Comment: @TravisJ - You deserve half the accepted-answer rep just for creating the complex scenario to test against. Thanks. (Karma is coming your way ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a different approach which does 'pre-processing':

```
var grid = (function(){

  var table = $("#table")[0], a=[], cell, i, j, k, l, y;

  for (i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++) a[i] = [];

  for (i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++) {
      y = 0;
      for (j=0;j<table.rows[i].cells.length;j++) {
          while (a[i][j + y]) y++;
          cell = $(table.rows[i].cells[j]);
          xspan = parseInt(cell.attr('rowspan') || 1);
          yspan = parseInt(cell.attr('colspan') || 1);
          for (k=0;k<xspan;k++) {
              for (l=0;l<yspan;l++) {
                  if(i + k < table.rows.length) a[i + k][j + y + l] = [i,j];
              }
          }
      }
  }

  return a;

})();

colorCell(1,2,'red');
colorCell(2,3,'green');
colorCell(3,3,'blue');

function colorCell(i,j,s){
    var a = grid[i][j];
    $(table.rows[a[0]].cells[a[1]]).css('background-color', s);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27HuN/26/)

Comment: Fails for more complex models.

Comment: I added a complex model as a comment to the question above (you can copy paste the html from that and test it with yours).

Comment: Updated and tested with your complex model.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is custom, and so your solution must also be custom. There is no simple generic way to approach this because of how departed the table is from the expected structure. Remove the commented out `td` elements and you will see the true shape of what the script is dealing with.

As in all good optimization, you should do some work up front. Use class names or data-attributes to mark which cell is which when you prepare them, and the work afterwards will dramatically decrease. Doing no work up front will cost you later in the end, as you can see from costly calculations and workarounds such as the suggested plugin.

See this jsfiddle for an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/27HuN/2/

In case something happens to it, here is a copy

*html*

```
<table id="table" border="1" cellpadding="10" style="text-align:center;">
<tbody>
    <tr class="0">
        <td class="0-0">(0,0)</td>
        <td class="0-1">(0,1)</td>
        <td class="0-2">(0,2)</td>
        <td class="0-3">(0,3)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="1">
        <td class="1-0">(1,0)</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="1-1 1-2">(1,1) (1,2)</td>
        <!--<td></td>-->
        <td rowspan="2" class="1-3 2-3">(1,3)<br/>(2,3)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="2">
        <td class="2-0">(2,0)</td>
        <td class="2-1">(2,1)</td>
        <td class="2-2">(2,2)</td>
        <!--<td></td>-->
    </tr>
    <tr class="3">
        <td class="3-0">(3,0)</td>
        <td class="3-1">(3,1)</td>
        <td class="3-2">(3,2)</td>
        <td class="3-3">(3,3)</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>​
```

*js*

```
$('.1-2').css('background-color', 'red');
$('.2-3').css('background-color', 'green');
$('.3-3').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Note that this is a *simple* example, and you would probably want to use class names which were not just numbers. Perhaps `r0c0`, `r2c3` type of markup, or something more verbose to logically represent these positions.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts, and I agree that pre-processing saves work, but in this case I'm interested in the availability of a convenient (and easy-to-understand) function that does away with the need for preparation. I'm also just interested in what clever tricks people might come up with. Thanks for the answer regardless; I'm sure it'll help a future visitor with a more practical purpose than mine!

Comment: @acheong87 - I guess I could automate the class name assignment if you did not want to do it yourself.

Comment: Right, but in automating that, you'd end up doing the same work I'm looking to have a clever function do, _i.e._ you would need to compensate for `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes as you go. Of course, by your method, the client would only have to calculate things once, which is the advantage of pre-processing you're talking about, and which I wholly agree with. But that _one_ time (or many times) we must do such calculations, what is the easiest way? That's essentially what I'm asking. (In your current answer, you're basically saying, "The easiest way is... your brain (doing it manually).")

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it in JSFiddle... Took some time though...

```
var table = $("#table")[0];

SetColumnColor(1, 2, 'red');
SetColumnColor(2, 3, 'green');
SetColumnColor(3, 3, 'blue');

function SetColumnColor(rowIndex, cellIndex, color){

    var actualRowIndex = GetActualRowIndex(table, rowIndex, cellIndex);
    var actualCellIndex = GetActualCellIndex(table.rows[actualRowIndex], cellIndex);
    $(table.rows[actualRowIndex].cells[actualCellIndex]).css('background-color', color);
}

function GetActualCellIndex(row, cellIndex) {
    var actualCellIndex = cellIndex;
    $(row.cells).each(function(index) {
        var colSpan = parseInt($(this).attr('colspan'));
        if(colSpan != NaN && colSpan > 0)
        {
            //alert(colSpan);
            actualCellIndex = actualCellIndex - colSpan + 1;
        }
    });

    return actualCellIndex;
}

function GetActualRowIndex(table, rowIndex, cellIndex) {
    var actualRowIndex = rowIndex;

    if(table.rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex] != null)
        return rowIndex;

    $(table.rows).each(function(index) {
        if(rowIndex <= index)
            return actualRowIndex;
        var realCellIndex = GetActualCellIndex(this, cellIndex);
        //alert("Row:" + index + "(" + realCellIndex + "," + cellIndex+ ")");
        var rowSpan = parseInt($(table.rows[index].cells[realCellIndex]).attr('rowspan'));
        if(rowSpan != NaN && rowSpan > 0)
        {
            //alert(rowSpan + "(" + index + "," + realCellIndex + ")");
            actualRowIndex = actualRowIndex - rowSpan + 1;
        }
    });

    return actualRowIndex;
}
```

A working demo is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/27HuN/9/)

Comment: Fails for more complex models.