# Dynamically highlight td in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

***Problem***

How to highlight dynamically a selected td?

***Codepen***

[Pen here](https://codepen.io/legeo/pen/MqYarz)

***Code***

The map is a 2d array random generated, something like this:

```
map = [[1,1,1,1,0],
       [1,0,0,0,0],
       [1,0,1,1,1],
       [1,0,0,0,1],
       [1,1,1,0,1]]
```

I can move the player 3 squares per turn and, one of this squares is his actual position. I used this function to call the movement:

```
function movements(character){
    var possibleMovement=3;
    let coord=character.actualPosition; 
        let row = $($("#tableGame tr")[coord.row]);
        let cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell]);

    forward(row, cell, possibleMovement, character);
    backward(row, cell, possibleMovement, character);
    goUp(row, cell, possibleMovement, character);
    goDown(row, cell, possibleMovement, character);
};
```

and with the functions below I try to highlight the cells where the character can actually move.

```
function forward(row, cell,possibleMovements, character){
    for(var i = 0; i<possibleMovements; i++){
        cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell+i]);
        var tile = $(".tile", cell).addClass('possibleSteps');
    };
};

function backward(row, cell, possibleMovements, character){
    for(var i = 0; i>=possibleMovements; i--){
        console.log('sei qua');
        cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell+i]);
        var tile = $(".tile", cell).addClass('possibleSteps');
    };
};
```

***Task***

I need to highlight the tiles near the character:

- Two tiles above `character.actualPosition`
- Two tiles below
- Two tiles at his right
- Two tiles at his left

  [image: testImage]

These are the two " testing function "

```
function forward(row, cell,possibleMovements, character){
    for(var i = 0 ; i<possibleMovements; i++){
        cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell +i]);
        var tile = $(".tile", cell).addClass('possibleSteps');
        console.log([coord.row] + "<<<row" + [coord.cell+i] + "<<<cell");
    };
};

function backward(row, cell, possibleMovements, character){

    possibleMovements= possibleMovements*-1;

    for(var i = 0 ; i>possibleMovements; i--){
        cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell+i]);
        var tile = $(".tile", cell).addClass('possibleSteps');
        console.log([coord.row] + "<<<row" + [coord.cell-i] + " <<<cell");
    };
};
```

Comment: I really like what you done here. Its hard for me to tell how you implement that movement logic, but I wonder if it wouldnt be easier if you'd add to your boardGame table cells data-* attributes (more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) like `data-x-pos` and `data-y-pos` and then it would be much easier to traverse and select cells via jQuery selector like `$("td[data-x-pos=4][data-y-pos=3]")`. Just a suggestion thou, good luck with your work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment i think i'm one step near the solution thanks to this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930892/selecting-an-arbitrary-cell-in-a-table-by-row-and-column-number), i will update as soon as possibile, right now i go over the bug of random spawned  box-shadowed tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found an answer. I want to say thanks [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930892/selecting-an-arbitrary-cell-in-a-table-by-row-and-column-number)  because it helps me a lot to find a solution that works.

The final functions to highlight the tiles near the character are these

```
function movements(){
    let possibleMovement=3;
    let row = character.actualPosition.row;
    let cell = character.actualPosition.cell;
    forward(possibleMovement, row, cell);
    backward(possibleMovement, row, cell);
    goUp(possibleMovement, row, cell);
    goDown(possibleMovement, row, cell);

};

function forward(possibleMovements, row, cell){

    let charRow = row;
    let charCell= cell;
    var table = $("table")[0];

    for(var i = 0; i<possibleMovements; i++){
        let cell = table.rows[charRow].cells[charCell+i]; // This is a DOM "TD" element
        let $cell = $(cell);
        $(cell).addClass('possibleSteps');
    };
};

function backward(possibleMovements, row, cell){
    let charRow = row;
    let charCell= cell;
    var table = $("table")[0];

    for(var i = -1; i>(possibleMovements*-1); i--){
        let cell = table.rows[charRow].cells[charCell+i]; // This is a DOM "TD" element
        let $cell = $(cell);
        $(cell).addClass('possibleSteps');
    };
};

function goUp(possibleMovements, row, cell){
   let charRow = row;
    let charCell= cell;
    var table = $("table")[0];

    for(var i = -1; i>(possibleMovements*-1); i--){
        let cell = table.rows[charRow+i].cells[charCell]; // This is a DOM "TD" element
        let $cell = $(cell);
        $(cell).addClass('possibleSteps');
    };
};

function goDown(possibleMovements, row, cell){
    let charRow = row;
    let charCell= cell;
    var table = $("table")[0];

    for(var i = -1; i<possibleMovements; i++){
        let cell = table.rows[charRow+i].cells[charCell]; // This is a DOM "TD" element
        let $cell = $(cell);
        $(cell).addClass('possibleSteps');
    };
};
```

The main solution was to understand this 4 lines of code, and how i can iterate through them:

```
    var table = $("table")[0];
    let cell = table.rows[charRow].cells[charCell+i]; // This is a DOM "TD" element
    let $cell = $(cell);
    $(cell).addClass('possibleSteps');
```